# How to update a specific row of a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to update a datatable in VB.net based on the other column value

```
| Column_1 |   Column_2 | Column_3 |
___________ ____________ ____________
|    2     |    1       |           |
___________ ____________ ____________
|    5     |    3       |           |
___________ ____________ ____________
|    4     |    2       |           |
___________ ____________ ____________
|    1     |    7       |           |
___________ ____________ ____________
|    8     |    9       |           |
___________ ____________ ____________
```

What i need is for `column1 value` **5** , i need `column 3` to be **1** and for the remaining row it should be zero.

What i have tried is

```
Dim CandidateRow As DataRow
CandidateRow = datatable.select("Column_1" = & rbl.selectedvalue).FirstOrDefault  ' datatable value here rbl.selected value would return 5
CandidateRow("Column_3") = 1
```

It is not updating the Datatable.

So what can be done to perform it

Comment: Can you please make fiddle?
You can do this at front end also.

Comment: @KuashalKhamar fiddle for what?? can we make fiddle for vb.net? if so please give me the link

Comment: You can do this work by using Jquery also.

Comment: do this work by using Jquery or javascript. No need to do using vb.net.

Comment: Have you read the question properly? I need it in vb.net my datatable is in vb.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below c# code and convert it to vb.net

```
foreach(DataRow row in table)
    {
       if(row["Column_1"]!=null and row["Column_1"].ToString()=="5")
         {
            row["Column_3"]=1;
         }
       else
         {
           row["Column_3"]=0;
         }
    }
//call AcceptChanges() to persist changes made.
table. AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: and you need to call [acceptchanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to persist the value in datatable.!! It worked..!! I never thought this way..! :)